# set delay dynamic on retryWhen

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, delay, retrywhen

Is it possible to set the delay value dynamic after every retry. I tried it like this but it looks lite it keeps the value which is set initial.

```
imageController(epgData: EpgDataDTO[], showOrMovie: string){
    var retryAfterMilliSeconds = 1000;
    epgData.forEach( (data) => {
        this.getImagesFromMovieDB(data.title).pipe(
            retryWhen((error) => {
                return error.pipe(
                    mergeMap((error: any) => {
                            if(error.response.status === 429) {
                                const retryAfter = error.response.headers;
                                retryAfterMilliSeconds = +retryAfter['retry-after'] * 1000
                                console.log(retryAfterMilliSeconds); // it tells me the correct value here but the retry happens every 1000ms
                                console.log(data.title);
                            }else{
                                this.errorHandling(error)
                                return of("error");
                            }
                            return of("error");
                        }),
                    delay(retryAfterMilliSeconds),
                    take(5)
                )
        }))
        .subscribe( (res) => {
            console.log(res.status);
            console.log(res.headers);

        });
    })
}
```

Comment: You should initialise the `retryAfterMilliSeconds` outside of the function and reset it once the request is made.

Comment: this is running on a node.js so server so the requests in the foreach loop run async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were VERY close!  To get this to work, all I had to do was move the `delay(retryAfterMilliSeconds)` to after the return value of the `mergeMap()` operator to tie it to the same observable.  Without this it would randomly delay the RETURN from `mergeMap()` which would be random for which Observable was actually delayed.

I put this up in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-54027303) to test it.  Click on 'Console' at the bottom of the far right frame to see results.

Here is the function from that StackBlitz:

```
imageController(epgData: EpgDataDTO[], showOrMovie: string){
    var retryAfterMilliSeconds = 1000;
    epgData.forEach( (data) => {
        this.getImagesFromMovieDB(data.title).pipe(
            retryWhen((error) => {
                return error.pipe(
                    mergeMap((error: any) => {
                            if(error.response.status === 429) {
                                const retryAfter = error.response.headers;
                                retryAfterMilliSeconds = +retryAfter['retry-after'] * 1000
                                console.log(retryAfterMilliSeconds); // it tells me the correct value here but the retry happens every 1000ms
                                console.log(data.title);
                            }else{
                                this.errorHandling(error)
                                // return of("error"); <-- unnecessary since this will be executed with next statement
                            }
                            return of("error").pipe(delay(retryAfterMilliSeconds));
                        }),
                    // delay(retryAfterMilliSeconds),
                    take(5)
                )
        }))
        .subscribe( 
            (res) => {
                // console.log(res.status);
                // console.log(res.headers);
                const elapsedTime = Math.round(((new Date()).getTime() - startTime) / 1000);
                console.log(`'${res.status}' is Ok - total elapsed time ${elapsedTime} seconds`);
            }
        );
    })
}
```

Some other notes:

- The return from `getImagesFromMovieDB()` is actually important - it needs to return a unique observable for every call for this to work, please ensure this is the case.  I simulated this in the StackBlitz by constructing the Observable return with `delay`.
- As you can see I changed the first function inside the `.subscribe()` to print out the total elapsed time taken to get valid data for this `res.status`.  I did this only to show for each emission that it correctly takes the sum of all delays. 
  It is retried after every failure for a random amount of time (I arbitrarily chose between 5 and 10 seconds), as returned by the response header in your original function.
- Minor point: you have two returns from mergeMap `return of("error")` but the first is unnecessary since the second will be immediately executed, so I commented that one out.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you very much for your effort :)